# Clicked Button without response in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to first select `Unsubscription`, then click `Continue`.
[image]

I tried to find by `Selector`, `xpath`, and execute raw javescript. However, after clicking the button `Continue`, the page does not load the expected information. I saw the button color changed from gray to orange.

Below is my current code

```
unsubscripeButton = self._driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#actionType3')
ActionChains(self._driver).move_to_element(unsubscripeButton).perform().click()
continueButton = self._driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#pwt_form_Button_0')
ActionChains(self._driver).move_to_element(continueButton).click(continueButton).perform()
```

And this is the HTML code responsible for the `Continue` button.
[image]

This is the `Unsubscription` and `continue` button after `Unsubscription is clicked:

```
<tr>        
    <td class="tableform" nowrap>
        <input id="actionType3" name="actionType" type="radio" value="U"/>Unsubscription
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the `Continue` button is like this

```
<tr class="buttonmenubox_R">
    <td valign="top" align="right">
        <div type="submit" dojoType="pwt.form.Button" name="_eventId_continue" value="Continue" class="button">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are invoking `click()` even before the element is properly loaded i.e. [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) / [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) calls are completed.

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  unsubscripeButton = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#actionType3")))
  ActionChains(self._driver).move_to_element(unsubscripeButton).click(unsubscripeButton).perform()
  continueButton = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.buttonmenubox_R div.button[name='_eventId_continue'][value='Continue']")))
  ActionChains(self._driver).move_to_element(continueButton).click(continueButton).perform()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  ```

---

### Update

As the element is still not clickable with *WebDriverWait* and *Actions* as an alternative you can use `execute_script()` method as follows:

```
unsubscripeButton = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#actionType3")))
ActionChains(self._driver).move_to_element(unsubscripeButton).click(unsubscripeButton).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.buttonmenubox_R div.button[name='_eventId_continue'][value='Continue']"))))
```

Comment: I added the `element_to_be_clickable`. The script completed without errors. However, the page still does not load as expected. The button changed from `grey` to `orange`.

Comment: @JOHN I made a small change in the locator strategy, did you consider that in your test?

Comment: I tried changed to CSS selector to yours: `"span.button#pwt_form_Button_0>a.button#pwt_form_Button_0"` and I got timeout error. Then I tried to use the chrome console to locate the element. I got null.

Comment: is `"span.button > a.button#pwt_form_Button_0"` what you mean? But I have also tried this... the same result. The button turned Orange. But didn't load.

Comment: @JOHN Yeah, but does the previous line of code clicks on the `Unsubscription` button at all? Can you update the question with the text based HTML of the `Unsubscription` button and of `Continue` button once the `Unsubscription` button is already clicked?

Comment: Yes. The unsubscription button is clicked.

Comment: Take a look on the HTML on `Continue`. It looks different in the inspect window

Comment: @JOHN Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: @JOHN Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Still timeout error. It seems that the element cannot be found. I tried in the Console. But I am not sure why there is a difference between source code and inspect element.

Comment: @JOHN Can you find the element with the locator within my answer within Inspect Element?

Comment: No. I tried ```document.querySelector("tr.buttonmenubox_R div.button[name='_eventId_continue'][value='Continue']")``` return `Null`

Comment: Hmm, possibly the HTML you provided is incorrect, please cross check

Comment: @JOHN Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void waitForElementClickable(By locator) {
         Webdriverwait wait = new WebdriverWait(driver,30);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Some error/exception while waiting for element to click -> " + locator.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

pass the locator as a parameter like this and wait till the element is clickable..
call this method before clicking , so that it would wait until the element is clickable and perform click operation.